# How to add environment variables to Tomcat 7 GUI service for windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, environment-variables, tomcat7

We've successfully setup tomcat 7 for windows and jruby but now we need to set an environment variables(RAILS_ENV and some other variable) before starting Tomcat.

We start Tomcat using the GUI on the lower right, and I was wondering how to add the variables in that gui. As usual windows isn't helpful enough with the vague terms for startup like:

class, method, arguments(has the value "start"), timeout and mode(has value "jvm")

So where do I add my environment variable here? I am guessing in arguments separated by a space? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows you can add environment variables under

Control Panel -> System -> Advanced -> Environment variables (the button at the bottom)

Then you can add a variable like JRUBY_OPTS with value --1.9